# My font in Word always returns to italic after I change it to regular

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, language, office365

I write papers in Word in 2 languages in the same files. My other language except for English is right-to-left language. When I write in my language, word changes my font in English only to italic. Every time I need to ctrl+a all the file, then ctrl+d to enter "font" section and change the font style to "regular". After I continue writing, and changing from time to time the language in the file, the font in English (only in English) returns to be italic again.

It seems like a bug but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Office 2010 is very nearly out of support and is not getting feature updates. Are you able to try a newer version?

Comment: I corrected it. I have Microsoft Office 365ProPlus.

Comment: That is a newer version as I suggested. If I post this as an answer - will you accept is as Answer?

Comment: I don't understand what is the answer?

Comment: Your first post says (Tag) Office 2010 and then you said you moved to (or had) Office 365.  Is that what you did?  Maybe I misunderstood

Comment: I made a mistake. I wrote office 2010 instead of office 365. My problem still remains.

Comment: With Office 365, I cannot see a reason for this.  One: try two different documents (different languages) on another Office 365 machine.  Two:  uninstall Office, restart, install Office and update fully, then try the documents again

Answer (score 0):

> > When I write in my language

<< Would you please tell me what your language is? I test in Word for Office 365, type some characters randomly in Arabic (Egypt) from right to left. Then English fonts still be regular.

I would like to give some suggestions that I hope they could be helpful.

1. Check this problem in a new blank document. If the problem does not occur with new blank document, please go to Styles (Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S) to check if there is a certain style set italic for content. You could also copy all content to a new blank document, then choose Keep Text Only in Paste Option. Reset the style for your papers.
2. If the problem still exists in a new blank document, please run Word in safe mode for a test. Please type “winword /safe” in Run dialog and click “OK”. It could rule out the Word add-ins’ effect. If nothing works, you could try to go to File > Options > Add-ins > Manager, COM Add-ins > Go, uncheck the COM Add-ins to have a check.
3. After you change the font style to "regular" in Font windows, please click Set As Default. Additionally, rename the Normal template (Normal.dotm). Close all the files of Office and show the hidden files. Go to C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates, then find the Normal.dotm and rename it. This file will be automatically generated when reopen Word.
4. When the steps above do not work, it’s recommended to reset user options and registry settings in Word, please refer to this article: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/reset-options-and-settings-in-word. The Easy Fix tool you could have a try first.

But please note, follow the steps about registry carefully. Serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Before you modify it, back up the registry for restoration in case problems occur. Please refer to this article about how to back up and restore the registry in Windows: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322756

5. At last, as John said, you could uninstall Office completely, and reinstall Office 365. To uninstall Office 365, you could refer to: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8. There is also a tool in article you could download and install to uninstall Office. To install Office 365, you could refer to: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/download-and-install-or-reinstall-office-365-or-office-2019-on-a-pc-or-mac-4414eaaf-0478-48be-9c42-23adc4716658.