# Word italicize when I switch languages in the document

Tags: microsoft-word

This relates to this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1500872/my-font-in-word-always-returns-to-italic-after-i-change-it-to-regular). None of the methods worked for me, but I think I've figured out the root of the problem - math mode. After going out of math mode, everytime I switch from hebrew to english, the english font is italicized. This is probably because math mode is italicized.

I've checked the document settings. My english font should be standard, yet everytime I switch languages, this problem occures. Interestingly, you can trigger this bug **once** by entering math mode, and it will keep returning every once in a while, even when you're not using math mode at all.

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0):

### In Word the Italics command is *not* a command to make the text Italics. Rather it is a toggle.

Italics might have been applied through math mode or something else. When you turn Italics off, you are toggling this setting in the math mode. When you then turn math mode (with its Italics setting) you are toggling the state again and turning Italics on.

**The sequence to bring this about:**

1. Turn on Math Mode or apply a Paragraph Style that includes Italics
2. Turn off Italics (and perhaps type)
3. Turn off Math Mode or switch to a different paragraph style that does not have underlying Italics.
4. The text typed will be in Italics.

*Other toggle font attributes are Bold and Underlined.*

I generally recommend that when using multiple languages in a document that you use language-specific styles for everything other than the base language. See my article [Using Styles for Proofing Language Settings](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/using-styles-for-proofing-language-settings/0a1bbf21-eaac-4044-afe6-253bfc47d65f) on the Microsoft site.